# Preserving JavaScript data types in JQuery data objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, types

I'm looking for a way to preserve a JavaScript datatype when saving it using JQuery.data(). Here is my code:

```
var test = new Task()
console.log(test) // is of type "Task"
$('#page-header')
  .data(test) // Here I am saving the object.
console.log($('#page-header')
 .data()) // is not of type task
```

So recently I switched my "class" declarations from something like this:

```
var Task = function(id) {
    this.id = id;
    this.DoSomething = function(){}
}
```

to this:

```
class Task {
     constructor(id) {
       this.id = id;
     }
     DoSomething() {}
}
```

Which is great, and comes with a lot of extra help from the vscode, and better jsdoc documentation, but now it seems like I can't access my functions after saving them using $.data(). I've been getting around this using Object.assign(T(), {whatever the $.data() is}), but I feel like there should be a better option. I've searched and can't find anything at the moment but maybe i'm not asking the right question, thanks

Comment: `data(object)` is not the correct way to put an object to an element.  `data(key, value)` is.  `data(key)` is the getter.  `data(key, value)` is the setter

Comment: Thanks that was it, I knew it was something small like that. If you make it an answer i'll mark it correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to set the data attribute incorrectly.

```
data(key) //getter
data(key, value) //setter
```

If you want to set the object on the element as a data object, you should give both the key to identify it, and the value it should return for the getter version.

Comment: There is a close reason for typos... Just sayin'.

Comment: The close reason text: "This question was caused by **a problem that can no longer be reproduced** or **a simple typographical error**. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers..." Seems like it fits here.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/L21c7g86/1/  @MikeMcCaughan It's easily reproducible and is not a typo.  Not using a method correctly is not a typo.  Changing the logic to fix the problem does not make it "no longer reproducible".  If you feel I have abused the system in answering this question, rather than voting to close it for a reason I do not agree with, please feel free to flag the answer for moderation review.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is to attach some data structure to a DOM element (presumably for later reference in relation to a click event or some such thing) you can just assign that value as a property of the DOMNode.

```js
class Foo{
  constructor(){
    this.x = "bar";
  }
  
  value(){
    return this.x;
  }
}

let foo = new Foo();
const test = document.getElementById('test');
test.myFoo = foo;

test.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  console.log('in click');
  console.log(event.target.myFoo.value());
});

console.log(test.myFoo.value());
```

```css
#test{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid #333;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
</div>
```